# writing a function that gives an element an id

Tags: javascript

I am building a tic tac toe game and i want to give each of the 9 input boxes an id corresponding to their position. Tried lots of stuff but nothings working as intended.

```js
const board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

function id() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    return i
}

function render() {
  board.forEach((cell) => {
    const element = document.createElement('div')
    element.innerText = cell
    element.classList.add("playBox")
    element.id = id()
    document.querySelector("#grid-container").appendChild(element)
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      element.innerText = 'x'
    })
  });
}

render()
```

```html
<div id="grid-container"></div>
```

Comment: Your `id` function does not work as you expect. It simply enters the for loop once, then returns 1. The value of `i` is not remembered on the following call, as it is a local variable.

Comment: Also you have from 0-8, just use the positions in the grid

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the function passed to `forEach` contains the index of the current element. You can use that instead of the incorrect `id` function:

```
function render(){
   board.forEach((cell, index) => {
      const element = document.createElement('div')
      element.innerText = cell
      element.classList.add("playBox")
      element.id = index + 1

      document.querySelector("#grid-container").appendChild(element)

      element.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
         element.innerText = 'x'
      })
   });
}
```

Comment: beginning `id` with a number is asking for problems